# Simple HTML Templating Under Windows

Tags: html, windows, templating

I have spent days trying to find a solution under windows for how to do very simple HTML templating under windows.

I don't want to use any solution that requires me to download and configure Ruby or Python or some way to compile javascript locally.

I am looking for a simple, basic solution.  Minimalism is my interest.

All I want to do is writer an HTML file but be able to insert blocks of pre-made HTML in by inserting a tag.

For example:

I want to be able to put in:

```
#menu1
```

and when this is compiled it will produce:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link four</a></li>
</ul>
```

Basically, I want to be able to arbitrarily define tags that result in substitutions of per-defined text.

And if I have a hundred different name.html.template files (or whatever they would be called), and if they all reference:

```
#menu1
```

Then I should be able to modify the definition of menu1, recompile the templates, and have outputted updated .html files.

What are simple ways of achieving this? I don't want to download a whole static website generator like Jekyll, or I don't want to use server side includes nor do I want to use PHP to do this.  I just want a simple program or text editor or something that well let me substitute tags for predefined arbitrary text.

Does a program like this exist?  Is there a text editor or HTML editor for windows that will do this?  Is there some kind of web browser based text editor that has this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to use jQuery.

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("template.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your solution is a viable solution. And yet, I should be able to do this all on my computer and render complete HTML without having to rely on any Java script.